# jQuery X-Ray Effect to Reveal Data Points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a client who wants to have an X-Ray effect that reveals clickable data points. A slider would be used to move a viewing window over an image, that would reveal an x-ray, or secondary image as the slider is moved. I've adapted Eli Kirk's X-Ray effect (http://elikirk.com/2013/12/02/draggable-x-ray-effect-using-css-javascript/) to get what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/xfxLx/3/. The jQuery UI portion of it is easy enough:

```
var artWidth = 300;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.xraySlider').slider({
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      var newLeft = (ui.value / 100) * (artWidth - 100);
      $('.xrayWindow').css({'background-position': (newLeft * -1) + 'px 0px', "left": newLeft + "px" });
}
   });
 });
```

The problem I'm having is making clickable data points that would be revealed by the window as it is slid across the main image. The data points would be fairly simple shapes (like, say, a black circle), that the user could click on once revealed by the x-ray window, to reveal a popup with more info. I've beat my head against the wall trying to come up with a workable solution (if this wasn't bad enough, it all has to work in IE7, so I've ruled out canvas as well).

If this effect won't work under the confines listed (which I've told them might be the case, since I have yet to come up with a viable solution), that's fine, but I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed yoput HTML, setting an inner element to the xray, that will hold the points

```
<div class="artifact-hold">
  <div class="artifact">
    <div class="xrayUpper"></div>
    <div class="xrayWindow">
        <div class="innerXray">
            <div class="point" id="brain"></div>
            <div class="point" id="heart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="xraySlider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, the JavaScript changes slightly

```
  var artWidth = 300;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.xraySlider').slider({
            slide: function(e, ui) {
                var newLeft = (ui.value / 100) * (artWidth - 100);

        $('.xrayWindow').css({"left": newLeft + "px" });
        $('.innerXray').css({"left": -newLeft + "px" });
            }
        });  
  });
```

And CSS is changed to make the xray clip the contents (with overflow hidden), and the inner has the background image instead of the xraywindow. also, some styling to the points.

```
.innerXray {
      width: 300px;
      height: 490px;
      position: absolute;
      background: url(http://s21.postimg.org/tpg6me1vb/bones.jpg) no-repeat;
      background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
.point {
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
#heart {
    left: 150px;
    top: 130px;
}
#brain {
    left: 150px;
    top: 30px;
}
.xrayWindow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 490px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### [result](http://jsfiddle.net/xfxLx/4/)

Comment: I tried it, editing the original JSFiddle link I provided, but this doesn't seem to work. Did I miss something? http://jsfiddle.net/vrEeF/

Comment: Sorry, I miss the .xrayWindow when I post the CSS. The key is to delete the bacjground from it (it is now in the inner, and to set overflow: hidden. (I have added also more comment about that)

Comment: I added cursor:pointer; to the point class just to make sure they'd be clickable, and it works. I guess I was just overthinking it. Thanks for your help! Here's the final item in action: http://jsfiddle.net/vrEeF/1/